# Search AutoNumber field in Access via SQL (VB)

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to allow the 'user' to search for 'members' by searching for their member ID. Here is a screenshot of the database (design view).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7pMpT1WtgKDVU5MVkFYNXJjcTA/edit?usp=sharing

If in VB I search for the ID as an Integer it produces a datatype mismatch error (see below)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7pMpT1WtgKDMFVtYlFiWlpES0E/edit?usp=sharing

Sorry for asking another probably pointless question, thank you though - mean's a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in this line:

```
sqlstatement = "Select * from Members where ID = '" +  MemberID + "';"
```

It should be:

```
sqlstatement = "Select * from Members where ID = " +  MemberID + ";"
```

Since your **"ID"** field is **Autonumber**, you're checking condition with a string which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing

```
"WHERE ID = '" + MemberID + "';"
```

in your VB code. I think this might be your
problem. I guess it thinks the ID is string, 
and not int.

I am not very familiar with VB but
try it without the '' i.e. like this:

```
"WHERE ID = " + MemberID + ";"
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I'm thrown off and give up easy with such little errors.

Comment: NP, it was obvious by your error: "data type mismatch in criteria expression". Criteria expression is the expression in your WHERE clause. So it works now?

Comment: Oops, seems I came second again ;)